# Help me with the Clean URL problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an `.htaccess` file set up like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/    /member.php [L]
```

So when users type `http://domainname.com/home/` it goes to the member page,
but when they type `http://domainname.com/home` I get a `404` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your rule only applies if a / is added after the home part.

Off the top of my head, this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^home(/)? /member.php [L]
```

Comment: But this is giving me Internal Error when i put this
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^home(/)? /member.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^folder(/)? /folder.php [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery(/)? /gallery.php [L]

Only home works remaining folder and gallery are getting 500 Error